# Powershell : Module PSFTP - Download all files with a date more recent than local files

Tags: powershell, ftp

I'm new in Powershell and I want to download all the files whose date is more recent than the local files (folders and sub-folders of the FTP path).

Here is my current script :

```
$FTPServer = "ftp://xx.xx.xx.xx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx"
$FTPSessionName = "GERA_FTPSession"
$localPath= "E:\xxxx\"
$username = "***"
$password = "*******"


# Import a module of FTP code
# https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-FTP-Client-db6fe0cb
Import-Module PSFTP


$secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secstr

# connnection FTP
Set-FTPConnection -Credentials $Cred  -Server $FTPServer -Session GERA_FTP -UsePassive 
$FTPSessionName = Get-FTPConnection -Session GERA_FTP 

#import files and folders
Get-FTPChildItem  -Session $FTPSessionName -Recurse | Get-FTPItem  -Session $FTPSessionName -localpath $localPath -RecreateFolders -Overwrite -Verbose
```

Thanks for your help

Arnaud

Comment: See (though with use of different FTP clients): https://stackoverflow.com/q/59726516/850848 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/31306426/850848

Comment: Hi, Martin the constraint is that I am obliged to use the PSFTP module ...